# Moq Second setup overrides the value returned for the first stetup

Tags: moq

I have a setup for :

```
_fusionPORepMock.Setup(s => s.GetByFusionVersionID(It.Is<int>(i => i.Equals(123)))).Returns(_currentPO);

_fusionPORepMock.Setup(s => s.GetByFusionVersionID(It.Is<int>(i => i.Equals(111)))).Returns(_previousPO);
```

However Moq overrides the value for the first setup even if the arguments are different.
Any ideas or concrete solution for my problem?

I do not want to create another mock.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure why using `It.Is` in this way clobbers the first setup, but if you just pass the raw integer you'll get the behavior you'll expect (and with less code):

```
_fusionPORepMock.Setup(s => s.GetByFusionVersionID(123)).Returns(_currentPO);

_fusionPORepMock.Setup(s => s.GetByFusionVersionID(111)).Returns(_previousPO);
```

Comment: Thx for the answer Patrick, everything was ok with my code, but I just had another line of code down in the method where I was overriding the setup again with the _previous. Me.Equals(stupid). ;)